# Using lz4 compression in javascript without Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, lz4

I am trying to get LZ4 decompression to work client-side in pure JavaScript.

I found this [JavaScript library](https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4) but it's meant to be used with Node.js.
Within the same repository I found a [library](https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4/blob/master/lib/decoder-js.js) which can in theory be used in the browser.
The problem is that such library expects still Node.js buffers which again I don't have since I'm not using Node.js and all of this is happening client side (I logged a bug [here](https://github.com/pierrec/node-lz4/issues/9) to try and get a hold of some pointers for how to use it).

I then looked for a porting of Node.js buffers and I found this [repository](https://github.com/arextar/browser-buffer). The problem is that when I use it I get this error 
in both Chrome and Firefox:

`TypeError: this is not a typed array`

I logged this [bug](https://github.com/arextar/browser-buffer/issues/2) report for this.
I feel like combining those two libraries I am not too far from achieving lz4 decompression in pure JavaScript but having never worked before with ArrayBuffer, Uint8Array and Node.js I am struggling to connect the dots.

**My question:** Has anyone successfully managed to decompress LZ4 in pure JavaScript? Any advice or pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I will provide an IDEA not a solution, you can try this repository

https://code.google.com/p/lz4/

it has a pure c implementation of LZ4

you can compile that with clang to llvm bitcode

and when you have that, you use this https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

to get javascript out of the llvm bitcode

its like c to javascript compilation, it maybe sound crazy but if you look at what they already achieved... i dont know it could actually work.

take a look [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) they ported lots of things to javascript with this tool
for example this one: https://github.com/kripken/lzma.js

Comment: That is quite possibly the best answer in the history of the universe.

Comment: Emscripten is great and decently fast. The cost is in the malloc, memcpy (there & back), free. Remember, it's a heap simulator.

Comment: emscripten is great but only if you are fluent in C/C++ since you'll have to make A LOT of post-compile modifications to make the code reasonably usable/readable.. *not for the faint-hearted*